# Elasticsearch: HOW-TO delete a (cluster) setting

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, settings

my current luster configuration settings look like this :

```
{
  "persistent": {
    "indices": {
      "store": {
        "throttle": {
          "type": "none",
          "max_bytes_per_sec": "150mb"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "transient": {}
}
```

and am wondering how can i delete the **"max_bytes_per_sec"** part of the settings.

could you please advise on this one ?

Comment: I don't think you can delete it. If you have `"indices.store.throttle.type" : "none"` I think `max_bytes_per_sec` is ignored.

Comment: Did you ever change it manually?

Comment: thanks Andrei. it is true, that is ignored. but i just want to know how to delete it..

Comment: hi piyushGoyal. yes, i changes with a "put" request. what i do not know wis how to delete ti ?

Comment: I dont think so you can delete it once you manually set it although you can always revert to the default values. It's one and same thing.

Comment: thanks, but am not able to revert it. can you please provide an example ?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/cluster-update-settings.html#_store_level_throttling

Comment: This is a known issue in Elasticsearch: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6732.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

alright. i found how to delete a persistent setting:
you go to the defined data path of the master node,
more specifically, `nodes/0/_state` (in my case) 
and you delete the global state file. then restart elasticsearch.

Comment: NEVER access the data folder.
The correct reply is the one above, referencing https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/cluster-update-settings.html

Answer (score 19):

```
Resetting persistent or transient settings can be done by assigning a null value.

Refer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/cluster-update-settings.html

in your case it would be

PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "persistent" : {
        "indices.store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec" : null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Per documentation this is now (Elasticsearch 5.5) possible via the following:

> Resetting persistent or transient settings can be done by assigning a null value.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/cluster-update-settings.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example from ES documentation:

> PUT /_cluster/settings {
>       "persistent" : {
>           "indices.store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec" : "100mb"
>       } }

and

> PUT /_cluster/settings {
>       "transient" : {
>           "indices.store.throttle.type" : "none" 
>       } }

Comment: : i know that, since i did that. the question is how to delete it ?

Comment: You can't delete it. I meant you can use the same api to revert back to default value

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a remote cluster from the cluster settings by passing null values for each remote cluster setting.

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster": {
      "remote": {
        "cluster_two": { 
          "mode": null,
          "seeds": null,
          "skip_unavailable": null,
          "transport": {
            "compress": null
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/modules-remote-clusters.html