# Removing an Elasticsearch index setting

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I remove a dynamic setting from an index ? Not changing its value but removing it completely.

I must migrate a 2.x Elasticsearch cluster to latest 5.x version. Running the elasticsearch-migration plugin, I see a red warning (meaning "You cannot upgrade without fixing this problem.") in "Index settings" : "Replaced settings" -> `index.cache.query.enable` has been replaced by `index.requests.cache.enable`. But https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_settings_changes.html does not tell how to remove a setting, nor does https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/indices.html (unless I missed something).

I can add the new setting using the REST API : `curl -XPUT http://server:9200/index1/_settings -d"{ "index": { "requests": { "cache": { "enable": "true" } } } }"`. But this does not remove the old setting and the elasticsearch-migration warning does not go away.

Using the API again, I can change the `index.cache.query.enable` value from `true` to `false` but that is not removing it. I tried setting it to `null` but this has no effect. So I am stuck with a setting I cannot get rid off and that blocks the migration (according to the `elastic-migration` plugin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no solution to remove an index setting in Elasticsearch 2.x

That said, the error about `index.cache.query.enable` is not blocking. I updated the cluster from 2.x to 5.x without fixing that warning. The updated cluster runs fine and the problematic setting has been automatically moved to the `archived` namespace.

Answer (score 2):

In the snapshot restore API there is an [attribute `ignore_index_settings`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html#_changing_index_settings_during_restore); you don't have to change the setting in the old cluster.

Also in Elasticsearch 5.0+ you can [reset values by using `null`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/16054#issue-127216050), but this won't work for your use case. Just for the next migration ;-)

PS: It seems to be possible to [delete a file on the filesystem to remove any setting in the cluster state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33582239/573153), but I haven't tested this and I definitely would not recommend it.

Comment: Note that I did not use (and did not want to use) any snapshot.

Comment: I had a look in the index files to see if I could find something equivalent to the cluster settings, but I did not find any.

Comment: This was massively helpful, thanks. Confirmed for `index.refresh_interval` on ES 7.10, particularly good for ref. interval b/c of it's difficult-to-reproduce default non-set behavior