# Removing an archived Elasticsearch index setting

Tags: elasticsearch

In an Elasticsearch 5.x cluster, a deprecated setting in several indices has been moved to the archived namespace. How can I remove that useless setting ?

Following up on [Removing an Elasticsearch index setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986005/removing-an-elasticsearch-index-setting/46036657), after migrating a 2.x Elasticsearch cluster to 5.x, the 2.x index-level setting `index.cache.query.enable` has been moved to `archived.index.cache.query.enable`. I tried using the indices update API to remove this setting by setting it to null :

```
curl -XPUT http://server:9200/index1/_settings -d'{ "archive": { "index": { "cache": { "query": { "enable": null } } } } }'
```

Unfortunately, this only leads to an error :

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":"[SERVER][ip_address:9300][indices:admin/settings/update]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.archive.index.cache.query.enable] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},"status":400}
```

Note the additional `index` that appears in `index.archive.index.cache.query.enable`. It is automatically added when it is not provided and that is part of the issue : in the settings, the `archived` namespace is at the same level than the `index` namespace, it is not nested under it.

```
{
  "index1": {
    "settings": {
      "archived": {
        "index": {
          "cache": {
            "query": {
              "enable": "false"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1501560004104",
        "requests": {
          "cache": {
            "enable": "true"
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "OQ5GKLvKRZ-XUpd_dYCFdA",
        "version": {
          "created": "2040399",
          "upgraded": "5050299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this was resolved but here is the solution, 
[_reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) in 5.6 to remove the archived settings.

Ref:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/27533#issuecomment-347188242

Comment: I am no more able to test that solution. I accept that answer and I hope that other people will confirm it works.